# day vs week rep gain

Tags: support, reputation

When I hover over the triangle on StackExchange, I find I have gained 45 rep today, but only 30 this week.  Is there a different cutoff time?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not a different cut-off time, but rather how we calculate it, for "today" we count up the votes that happened today, where as with a week we track the net change throughout the week.

I'm going to look at changing this tomorrow (so that the day does the same as other intervals).  There are pros/cons on both solutions, but the consistency might be worth it here.

Here's the common case that leads to this:  A vote is deleted or undeleted that was *previously* created, this makes display a bit wacky since we don't show *removed* votes, or undeleted votes in the time they had the net effect, let's take an example:

- May: someone votes your post up, +10

  - your rep goes up 10 for the week, month, etc.
- June: say you edited later, someone removes that vote (or unaccepts an answer)

  - your rep goes down 5/10/15, etc for the week, month, etc.

Now from the *day* point of view (strictly looking at that range), your rep hasn't changed, no vote happened *then*.  However, there was a *net* effect on your rep, it's just that the 10 rep was removed (looking overall) back in may...or rather it no longer happened.

In your particular case, [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27828/calculate-the-unknown/27829#27829) was unaccepted, resulting in a -15 net when it happened today.

Comment: Thanks.  I don't really care much, but was curious how it could happen.